# Append error message only when radio button is not checked on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, radio-button

I am trying to show an error if a user presses submit and doesn't check one of the radio buttons. That part works fine. Now, my issue is that even when the radio button is checked and the user presses the button.. the error shows right before the form submits. Why is that error showing when the radio button is checked? Any help will be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);">
  <input type="submit" class="add-cart " value="Add">
  <br />

  <p class="option-name">Size : </p>
  <input type="radio" required="required" aria-required="true" id="product1" value="1" name="options[]" />
  <label class="label" for="product1">Small</label>

  <input type="radio" required="required" aria-required="true" id="product3" value="3" name="options[]" />
  <label class="label" for="product3">Medium</label>

  <input type="radio" required="required" aria-required="true" id="product4" value="4" name="options[]" />
  <label class="label" for="product4">Large</label>

  <input type="radio" required="required" aria-required="true" id="product5" value="5" name="options[]" />
  <label class="label" for="product5">X-Large</label>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0;
  $(".add-cart").click(function() {
    if (!$("input[name='options']").is(':checked') && count <= 0) {
      $(".option-name").append("<p class='option-error'>This field is required</p>");
      count++;
    }
  });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kxv2jpoj/1/)**

Comment: youre not lowering count...

Comment: @Jonasw I only did that to not append the same error message 20 times

Comment: in that case its much better to use a *boolean* then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not currently resetting between uses, here's a new version:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add-cart").click(function() {
    $(".option-error").html("");
    if (!$("input[name='options[]']:checked").val()) {
      $(".option-error").html("This field is required");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="javascript:void(0);">
  <input type="submit" class="add-cart " value="Add">
  <br />

  <p class="option-name">Size : <p class="option-error"></p></p>
  <input type="radio" required="required" aria-required="true" id="product1" value="1" name="options[]" />
  <label class="label" for="product1">Small</label>

  <input type="radio" required="required" aria-required="true" id="product3" value="3" name="options[]" />
  <label class="label" for="product3">Medium</label>

  <input type="radio" required="required" aria-required="true" id="product4" value="4" name="options[]" />
  <label class="label" for="product4">Large</label>

  <input type="radio" required="required" aria-required="true" id="product5" value="5" name="options[]" />
  <label class="label" for="product5">X-Large</label>
</form>
```

Comment: It has a small bug on the first click... error still shows up

Comment: @user4756836 updated it.  Please remember to mark as solution: it helps a lot.